# How to import modules in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have created a simple GAE app based on the default template. I want to add an external module like [short_url](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576918/). How do I do this? The directions that I have found so far are confusing and GAE doesn't seem to use PYTHONPATH for obvious reasons I guess.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Simply place the `short_url.py` file in your app's directory.

Sample App Engine project:

```
myapp/
    app.yaml
    index.yaml
    main.py
    short_url.py
    views.py
```

And in `views.py` (or wherever), you can then import like so:

```
import short_url
```

---

For more complex projects, perhaps a better method is to create a directory especially for dependencies; say `lib`:

```
myapp/
    lib/
        __init__.py
        short_url.py
    app.yaml
    index.yaml
    main.py
    views.py
```

```
from lib import short_url
```

---

Edit #2:
Apologies, I should have mentioned this earlier.  You need modify your path, thanks to Nick Johnson for the following fix.
Ensure that this code is run before starting up your app; something like this:

```
import os
import sys

def fix_path():
    # credit:  Nick Johnson of Google
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))

def main():
    url_map = [ ('/', views.IndexHandler),] # etc.
    app = webapp.WSGIApplication(url_map, debug=False)
    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fix_path()
    main()
```

---

Edit3:
To get this code to run before all other imports, you can put the path managing code in a file of its own in your app's base directory (Python recognizes everything in that directory without any path modifications).
And then you'd just ensure that this import

```
import fix_path
```

...is listed before all other imports in your `main.py` file.
Here's a [link to full, working example](http://bitbucket.org/abernier/yab/src/) in case my explanation wasn't clear.

Comment: I'm still getting an issue, even after I restart the app server with this layout.

from lib import short_url
ImportError: No module named lib

Comment: Thanks - it's working now. Where is the best place to call fix_path()? I'm calling it this way:

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fix_path()
    main()

And then I have this function called from my code:

def generate_key(id):
    import short_url
    return short_url.encode_url(id)

Is there somewhere I can call fix_path() that let's you keep all imports together at the top of the file?

Comment: @Brian: great. Glad you got it working.  I'll add another example to allow you to keep the imports in one spot.

Answer (score 5):

i will second the answers given by @Adam Bernier and @S.Mark, although adam's explains things is a bit more detail. in general, you can add any pure Python module/package to your App Engine directory and use as-is, as long as they don't try to work outside of the sandbox, i.e, cannot create files, cannot open network sockets, etc.

also keep in mind the hard limits:

- maximum total number of files (app files and static files): 3,000
- maximum size of an application file: 10 megabytes
- maximum size of a static file: 10 megabytes
- maximum total size of all application and static files: 150 megabytes

UPDATE (Oct 2011): most of these numbers [have been increased](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/10/app-engine-155-sdk-release.html) to:

- maximum total number of files (app files and static files): 10,000
- maximum size of an application file: 32MB
- maximum size of a static file: 32MB

UPDATE (Jun 2012): the last limit [was bumped up](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2012/06/google-app-engine-170-released-at.html) to:

- maximum total size of all application and static files: 1GB

Answer (score 1):

You can import python packages as ZIPs. This allows you to avoid the maximum file count.

The [app engine docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/diff27#zipimport_Support) address this.

> python 2.5: zipimport is supported.
>
> python 2.7: zipimport is not supported, but Python 2.7 can [natively import from .zip files.](http://docs.python.org/library/zipimport.html)

This is how I import boto.

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'boto.zip')
import boto #pylint: disable=F0401
from boto import connect_fps  #pylint: disable=F0401
```

The cons of this technique include having to manually re-archive many packages.

For example, *boto.zip* decompresses into the "boto" subdirectory, with the "boto" module  inside of it (as another subdirectory).

So to import boto naturally you may have to do from boto import boto, but this can cause weirdness with a lack of __init__.py.

To solve this, simply decompress, and archive the *boto* subfolder manually as boto.zip, and place that in your application folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since that url_shortener program written in python, you could just include in your source code and import it like other python modules.