# Using pygooglechart with GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

while i am using "from pygooglechart import PieChart3D" google app engne is reporting  "No module named pygooglechart" what may be the problem??

Comment: Almost certainly you don't have a module named `pygooglechart` in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upload modules that you want to use - you can put pygooglechart in your app's directory and it should work. See [How to import modules in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710861/how-to-import-modules-in-google-app-engine).

If the module you want to call uses any native C code, it won't work on Google App Engine, but I think pygooglechart is pure Python so it should be fine.

Comment: Here my point is how to add pygoogle chart api (library) not modules can you please help on this and when i am trying to add that pygoogle chart api in libraries it is reporting Fatal error when loading application configuration:
Invalid object:
the library "pygooglechart" is not supported

Comment: Does the error message go on to give a line number in your "app.yaml" file? Are you putting an instruction there to include pygooglechart? That only works for a small list of libraries that Google have set up for you - for any other library, you have to upload the module yourself. "Module" here means the same as "the code to run the library".

Comment: Are you trying to say setup.py of the library

Comment: No, you'll need to put the `pygooglechart.py` file in your app's directory. The question [How to import modules in Google App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710861/how-to-import-modules-in-google-app-engine) explains how to do this for the short_url module.