# PYTHONPATH conflict

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am trying to `import ZipCodeDatabase` in `helloworld.py`.

- `helloworld.py` exists at `/google-app-engine/helloworld`
- `ZipCodeDatabase` module exists `/usr/local/lib/python/python2.7/dist-packages`
- `PYTHONPATH` = `/usr/local/lib/python/python2.7/dist-packages;/usr/local/lib/python/`

When compiling `helloworld` I am still getting "`ZipCodeDatabase` module not found". Why isn't it being picked from the `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: thanks minitech, :) you beat me before i could make the edit thanks

Comment: @minitech you also put the spelling mistake back in!

Comment: @jamylak: What spelling mistake? `phyton`? Sorry, I was working off revision 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly doubt you've got a module called `ZipCodeDatabase`. That naming convention is typically reserved for a `class` that resides within a `module`. Modules are usually lowercase or lower_snake_case, to represent the file containing the module. I'm assuming you've installed `pyzipcode` here, but it may be a different module.

```
# assuming pyzipcode.py in the dist-packages directory
$ python -c 'from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase'
```

If I'm wrong above, then are you **sure** you're running the version of python that has the ZipCodeDatabase module installed?

Some troubleshooting steps:

```
$ which python
$ python --version
$ python -c 'import ZipCodeDatabase'
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ | grep -i zip
```

Also, is it really necessary for you to specify the `PYTHONPATH` line? Typically, the `site-packages` folder (and by extension I assume the `dist-packages` folder on Ubuntu) is included in the default `PYTHONPATH`, along with the current directory of the python module you're using.

How did you install the ZipCodeDatabase? Did you just drop the file in there? Try putting it alongside your `helloworld.py` file and try importing it then. Also, a full stack trace is useful information here, especially when others are trying to diagnose the problem you're having.

Edit:

Ok, now that I know you're using google app engine (should have been obvious from your use of paths - I'm sorry), it looks like it doesn't use the `site-packages` or `dist-packages` to load modules. You should create a sub-directory in your project with the relevant third party libraries, and add that sub-directory to your path. *Disclaimer:* I've never used GAE so I might be missing the mark with this.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2710892/10583) for how to structure your project and add the extra directory to your path from within the application.

Comment: I can use ZipCodeDatabase when i use it in idle, but having the error no module found when used in the google app engine program. i am not sure whether this is a google app engine question or general python question. I looked how to import modules in google app engine and that seems also not working for me.

Comment: @user189364 take a look at this answer and question then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710861/how-to-import-modules-in-google-app-engine