# Google app Engine with Twython Library on Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, twython, sys.path

I am trying to build a twitter app on google appengine using Python. I have used a Python Library called Twython to make the app on my Python script. However, when I try to use it in conjunction with google appengine, the application doesn't build i.e. I am having a problem installing Twython library on my google appengine Python script.

I have pasted Twython library I downloaded in the root folder of the app and used `sys.path.insert(0,Lib)` as mention in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359184/how-to-install-python-package-in-a-specific-directory) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850853/how-to-include-third-party-python-libraries-in-google-app-engine). However, nothing works. As I am a beginner Python developer and new to google appengine, I would much appreciate a very detailed answer.

I thank you for your effort in answering my question in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to solve the issue.

I was using a text editor to start with and I had already copied my **twython** library in a folder called **lib** in the root folder of the project where app.yaml lies.

I integrated GAE in Eclipse and tried to import my **twython** library. It was showing an error that "request library is missing". By then I was having a slight idea that it was probably an issue with dependencies of the library. So I included **requests** library then **request-oauthlib** and **oauthlib**. Then I used `sys.path.insert(0,lib)` after `import sys` in my lines of codes. It solved the problem.

Comment: Can you explain how you got the request library working in App Engine? I tried and the requests developers claim App Engine is not supported.