# Installing python-unicodecsv on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

im trying to use [unicodecsv](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv) in my python GAE application but I got the error "ImportError: No module named unicodecsv". So, I guess needs to be installed.
How can I install it?

I am new to this, so please bear with me before downvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a complete explanation for the solution here:
[How to import modules in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710861/how-to-import-modules-in-google-app-engine)

But I didn't need that "import fix_path" thing. Worked fine without that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the module in your application code.
download the module and put it into your app folder.