# Installing Unirest python module in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-module, unirest

Hi i am new to GAE and python. I am trying to create small web application in GAE using python. I intend to use [Unirest](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-python) module in application.

I followed instruction in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710861/how-to-import-modules-in-google-app-engine) and got following error.

> no module named poster.encode

How can i install unirest successfully in GAE  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `import sys` to your **main.py** and add these lines.

```
# inject './lib' dir in the path so that we can simply do "import ndb" or whatever there's in the app lib dir.
if 'lib' not in sys.path:
    sys.path[0:0] = ['lib']
```

Create the **lib** folder in the root of your project and copy the unirest folder in lib folder.

You can now import **unirest** and use your library.

But, why not use the standard method and library provide by Google App Engine ?

Comment: Can i use requests or urllib instead ?
Is there any other module **standard method and library** in appengine.

Comment: I found [urlfetch][1] useful.
[1]:https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/