# csv module doesn't work in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv

We are using Google App Engine with Python for our application. I already wrote code that exports data to CSV, using the csv module. But when I try to read from the CSV:

```
import csv

users_csv_file = self.request.get("users_csv_file")
csv_reader = csv.reader(users_csv_file)
```

I get this exception:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reader'
```

What is the problem and why can't I import csv?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710861/how-to-import-modules-in-google-app-engine

Comment: take another look at the example, you seem to have misunderstood it. What  is "users_csv_file" exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found the problem. I had a directory "csv" and when I imported `csv` it imported my local directory, which didn't have an attribute `reader`. I renamed the directory to "_csv" and this solved the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You have to pass in a file object, not a file name.

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print ', '.join(row)
```

> Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful
>   Spam

Comment: This was an answer.  Why the spam?