# google app engine - how to add lib folder?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter

I keep getting ImportError: No module named twitter when it's in my lib module

Details:

1. the twitter module is located in the lib directory.
2. The lib directory has an empty **init**.py
3. I'm getting the error on a page just outside the directory
4. When I take the twitter module out of the lib directory and just say import twitter, it works
5. When I put the twitter module back inside the lib and say from lib import twitter, or when I say import twitter, or saying import lib.twitter it says, go to **** and like it
6. I tried doing this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en , which suggests to:

To tell your app how to find libraries in this directory, create (or modify) a file named appengine_config.py in the root of your project, then add these lines:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

and then tried import twitter, and tried from lib import twitter, and it says, "haha, nice try."

Now what?

Comment: I don't think `lib` is supposed to be a module/package, it's supposed to be just a dir containing other modules/packages (donno if this has anything to do with your issue). Might be a good idea to show exactly your app's dir structure and pieces of the code causing the errors. Also better to show the errors quoted, not described. Is your app a multi-module one?

Comment: You got the last bit right with the "vendor.add('lib')" but you should then just "import twitter" , the vendor.add  add's to your python path, 'lib' is not a module or package.

Answer (score 10):

tl;dr - the comments are right. 'lib' is not a module, it's a folder containing modules. It needs to be on your Python import path *before* your `import twitter`, using the `vendor.add('lib')`, which should set up your import path correctly when you deploy or use dev_appserver.py. If you place the `vendor.add(lib)` snippet in `appengine_config.py` file and run dev_appserver.py or deploy, and the twitter module is inside `lib`, you should be able to `import twitter`. If you're running outside of App Engine/devappserver, you'll need to make sure `lib` is on the PYTHONPATH.

Here is the longer explanation of what the `lib` folder is; what vendoring is; and how they fit into the bigger picture of managing dependencies on App Engine.

With App Engine, you can specify some dependencies provided by the sandbox in app.yaml. You can se the list of available libraries [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en).  For any other dependencies (which can only be pure Python libraries), the libraries need to be directly included inside your project. Directly including the code for these dependencies as part of your project (rather than just listing them in requirements.txt and expecting them to get installed at deploy time) is commonly called 'vendoring'.

Now, even though we are including dependencies directly, we'd rather just use pip and a requirements.txt, for a few reasons I will mention below. But pip is usually used to install into libraries into the system libraries or a virtualenv, not into the project itself. So a feature was added to pip and a feature was added to App Engine to fix this.

The pip feature install dependencies into a folder rather than your system libraries or a virtualenv. You use the -t flag like this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib
```

Where 'lib' is the folder to install into. This way, you still specify your dependencies in requirements.txt, and use pip to install them, they just get installed right into the directory specified. As the comments noted, the lib folder is itself not a module - it just contains them. So your lib folder should not have an `__init__.py`, it should just contain a folder like 'twitter' that does have an `__init__.py`. Since `lib` is not a module, `from lib import twitter` doesn't actually make sense. Also note that `lib` is an arbitrary name, but the one we usually pick by convention.

There are a few big advantages to vendoring using pip rather than just manually downloading dependencies and adding them to the project. One advantage is you don't need to check the dependencies into source control - just add the requirements.txt, and tell other users to use the `pip -t` command to vendor the dependencies too. Another advantage is it's just more organized to cleanly separate your code from third-party modules. The point of the vendoring features is to keep these advantages while still following App Engine requirements to include the dependencies in the directory at deploy time.

The App Engine vendor extension which you are using was made to recognize that a folder contains modules that have been 'vendored' and add it to the path. That is the vendor extension you are using in your snippet. It makes sure the `lib` folder is on your import path so you can import the modules you installed into it.

Once you run the vendor.add command, you should be able to import your modules in the lib folder.  As the comment notes, you need to make sure it runs *before* `import twitter`. A good practice is to make sure those vendor commands run before anything else. You can accomplish this by putting that code inside a file named [appengine_config.py](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig?hl=en) in your directory. That's a special file that runs before anything else. Take a look at an example of doing that [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-flask-skeleton/blob/master/appengine_config.py).

A few last notes that might be helpful:

- `appengine_config.py` will run in the GAE environment or when you run dev_appserver, which emulates the GAE environment. However if you're ever running outside of a GAE environment, make sure your PYTHONPATH includes the `lib` folder you want to import from.
- Since you can vendor libraries using pip, you might ask why would you ever include a dependency using app.yaml? The answer is that since only pure Python libraries can be vendored, you still should use app.yaml dependencies for any libraries which need C libraries, such as MySQL.
- If you have vendored libraries and app.yaml libaries, you don't want to vendor libraries that will be in the GAE sandbox since the versions might conflict. In that case, it's a good idea to have a separate requirements.txt for dependencies you want to vendor, and dependencies you want included only when running locally but that GAE will provide in the sandbox. [Here](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/appengine-django-skeleton) is an example of that for MySQL.

Comment: what's the difference between `pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib` and navigating to the lib folder and doing `pip install <a third party module> -t . `?

Comment: Two differences. The first is that you're not using the requirements.txt, so if a new developer clones your repo, how do they know what to install? A requirements.txt is a standard way to list all the dependencies you need to run the project. The second difference is you are installing into the current directory (.) instead of lib/. This probably simplifies things for you because you don't need to change the import path at all using the vendor extension. That's fine if you prefer it, but the purpose of the lib folder is to cleanly separate which modules are third-party.

Comment: I just noticed you said "navigate to the lib folder". In that case there's no difference in terms of the folder structure or need to setup the import path. You are just installing into lib from a different directory.

Comment: @biil-prin awesome, I just read some of https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html . I'm glad you pointed out the cloning situation. Thanks! :)

Comment: Happy to help. One last trick you might find useful. If you type 'pip freeze' it will list all the modules you have installed. If you work within a virtualenv (highly recommended), you only install what you need, then you can type `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to autogenerate the file.

Comment: yeah I saw that too :). Looked handy. I finally got it working by paying closer to your 'However if you're ever running outside of a GAE environment, make sure your PYTHONPATH includes the lib folder you want to import from' statement. I tried the python path thing via the command line and bash profile.. bad idea. After everything, I had to do what was listed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710861/how-to-import-modules-in-google-app-engine, using `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))` because I wanted to run unittest in eclipse, which was importing my file

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a folder called "libs" (in the home directory of your webapp)
2. If one library, then just do: pip install -t libs/ your_library_name
3. if multiple libraries, do:
   pip freeze > requirements.txt,
   pip install -r requirements.txt -t libs
4. Now, create a file called appengine_config.py (in the home directory, again)
5. In the above file, add:
   `from google.appengine.ext import vendor
   vendor.add('libs')`

These get uploaded onto your app engine environment and you'll be able to run it!

Comment: Note, I think this is all for appengine python 2.7, not for python 3.