# Importing Python SendGrid on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, sendgrid

I have an App Engine project which I’d like to start using SendGrid with. I downloaded and installed the library and I can import `sendgrid` normally from the Python terminal. However, when I type `import sendgrid` in the GAE code, it gives me the following error message:

```
import sendgrid
ImportError: No module named sendgrid
```

I downloaded the SendGrid folder from GitHub and put it in the lib directory of my project. What am I missing?

Comment: Show us the details of your app folder structure.

Comment: code\lib\sendgrid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google app engine - how to add lib folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662595/google-app-engine-how-to-add-lib-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by installing SendGrid directly in lib dir of your project.

```
> pip install sendgrid -t lib
```

In order to do this, you need to have **appengine_config.py** in your root directory. It allows you to include third-party packages and its contents look like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib')
```

Then you just call import sendgrid and you are ready to go.